# I want to change My mediaplayer from one surafceview to other surafceview how to do that in android?

Tags: android, custom-controls, media-player, fullscreen, surfaceview

Hi I have a custom media player in my application it has full screen property so i am using two different layouts for both full screen and normal,
When use clicks full screen the media player has to change its surface from one to other,
How can i achieve this in android?
Thank you for your answers,Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the surfaceview by using

```
SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.customSurfaceViewID);
```

and then messing around with to get your fullscreen mode:

```
sv.setScaleX();
sv.setScaleY();
```

in your GLRender:

```
@Override /*landscape to portrait help*/
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float ratio = (float) width/height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 50);
}
```

Comment: i want to use two diffrent layouts so i have two different surafceviews?

Comment: hmmm... I don't understand the problem or why you are trying to use two different surface views. Maybe instead of explaining what exactly you want done; explain exactly what you expect to happen from the user's point of view. And explain what you mean by "my application has a full screen property." You already have this made?

Comment: my application works in portrait mode also portrait view is totally different form landscape all the controls will change their position so i want to use different layout with a new surfaceview.

Comment: so i'm guessing your mediaplayer controls are on the surfaceview? and when you hit "full screen mode" then you want the surfaceview to turn to landscape and take up the whole screen?

Comment: i have seperate custom controls when user hits fullscreen ,controls will change thier params.and some new view are added in fullscreen mode so i want to use different layout.